# Image responsiveness breaks in 320x568

Tags: html, css

My Code is like this

```css
.fairdetailimg {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.fairmonos {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
table {
    background-color: transparent;
}
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.fairmonos td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
.fairdet-image, .fairdet-image img {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
img {
    border: 0;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px)
responsive.css:1800
td.fair-border {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
td.fair-border {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 30% !important;
    word-break: break-word;
}
.fair-border {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.fair-mono {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.fairmonos .fair-img {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding-top: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="fairdetailimg">
   <table width="100%" class="fairmonos">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td width="70%">
               <div class="fairdet-image">
                  <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/nkY9oF/1.jpg">
               </div>
            </td>
            <td class="fair-border" width="30%">
               <div class="fair-logoinfo">
                  <div class="fair-mono">
                     India Art Fair
                  </div>
                  <div class="fair-img">
                     <a href="#">
                     <img class="img-responsive" src="https://image.ibb.co/czDaTF/2.jpg">
                     </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="fair-address">
                     <strong>Address: </strong>INDIA
                  </div>
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Everything works fine in higher resolutions but when it goes to lower resolutions it creates a white gap below main image as shown in the pic
[image]

How can I overcome this?

Comment: OK, so what do you want to happen with the words "Address: INDIA"?

Comment: @MrLister need to stay where it is, And mai nimage need to take up that full black space. (I can change the size of the image to what ever wanted).

Comment: I think the original image size is '256px' so it is not expanding after that height,Please check image height.

Comment: Still not clear what you want to happen. You should make a (mocked up) screenshot of how you want it to look. Should the picture to the left be cut off, or stretched? Should the picture to the right be kept small enough to keep everything (the words too) in place?

Comment: @MrLister I am trying to reduce the right side box elements as small as possible, And make the left side image as big as possible so that in both places it don't looks bad.

Comment: @MrLister or what size should be my left and right side images, So that i don't have to either stretch or crop both but have a descent view on browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a few edits just check below.

This is where Photoshop is useful i would say. I would create the image and then make my divs accordingly as some images which tend to get stretched don't look great at all.

```css
.fairdetailimg {
    /*margin-bottom: 20px;*/
}
.fairmonos {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
table {
    background-color: transparent;
}
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.fairmonos td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
.fairdet-image, .fairdet-image img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 380px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.fair-img{
width: 100%;
}
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
img {
    border: 0;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px)
responsive.css:1800
td.fair-border {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
td.fair-border {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 30% !important;
    word-break: break-word;
}
.fair-border {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.fair-mono {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.fairmonos .fair-img {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding-top: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="fairdetailimg">
   <table width="100%" class="fairmonos">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td width="40%">
               <div class="fairdet-image">
                  <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/nkY9oF/1.jpg">
               </div>
            </td>
            <td class="fair-border" width="30%">
               <div class="fair-logoinfo">
                  <div class="fair-mono">
                     India Art Fair
                  </div>
                  <div class="fair-img">
                     <a href="#">
                     <img class="img-responsive" src="https://image.ibb.co/czDaTF/2.jpg">
                     </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="fair-address">
                     <strong>Address: </strong>INDIA
                  </div>
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your image is responsive, you can either add a height to your image but this approach will make your image distorted.

**EXAMPLE 1**

```css
.fairdetailimg {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.fairmonos {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
table {
    background-color: transparent;
}
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.fairmonos td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
.fairdet-image, .fairdet-image img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
img {
    border: 0;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px)
responsive.css:1800
td.fair-border {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
td.fair-border {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 30% !important;
    word-break: break-word;
}
.fair-border {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.fair-mono {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.fairmonos .fair-img {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding-top: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="fairdetailimg">
   <table width="100%" class="fairmonos">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td width="70%">
               <div class="fairdet-image">
                  <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/nkY9oF/1.jpg">
               </div>
            </td>
            <td class="fair-border" width="30%">
               <div class="fair-logoinfo">
                  <div class="fair-mono">
                     India Art Fair
                  </div>
                  <div class="fair-img">
                     <a href="#">
                     <img class="img-responsive" src="https://image.ibb.co/czDaTF/2.jpg">
                     </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="fair-address">
                     <strong>Address: </strong>INDIA
                  </div>
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Or using background image with background-cover property

**EXAMPLE 2**

```css
.fairdetailimg {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.fairmonos {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
table {
    background-color: transparent;
}
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.fairmonos td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
.fairdet-image, .fairdet-image img {
    background: url('https://preview.ibb.co/nkY9oF/1.jpg') no-repeat center center / cover;
    width: 100%;
height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
img {
    border: 0;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px)
responsive.css:1800
td.fair-border {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
td.fair-border {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 30% !important;
    word-break: break-word;
}
.fair-border {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.fair-mono {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.fairmonos .fair-img {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding-top: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="fairdetailimg">
   <table width="100%" class="fairmonos">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td width="70%">
               <div class="fairdet-image">
                  
               </div>
            </td>
            <td class="fair-border" width="30%">
               <div class="fair-logoinfo">
                  <div class="fair-mono">
                     India Art Fair
                  </div>
                  <div class="fair-img">
                     <a href="#">
                     <img class="img-responsive" src="https://image.ibb.co/czDaTF/2.jpg">
                     </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="fair-address">
                     <strong>Address: </strong>INDIA
                  </div>
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```